# Как сделать прелоадер на время загрузки JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

На странице есть элемент HTML, стили которого назначаются Jquery плагином.
И пока страница подгружается вместе с JS, стили этого элемента прыгают

Comment: Что-то не сильно понятно что к чему. Прелоадеров реализаций куча, в чём вопрос?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Достаточно закрыть необходимые вам или все элементы на странице прелоадером, который будет исчезать после необходимых действий на странице.

Пример доработан. Версию с использованием библиотеки jquery можно считать устаревшей, но она была оставлена, чтобы показать, как делать не нужно.

Обновленный вариант (2019):

```js
function loadData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // setTimeout не является частью решения
    // Код ниже должен быть заменен на логику подходящую для решения вашей задачи
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  })
}

loadData()
  .then(() => {
    let preloaderEl = document.getElementById('preloader');
    preloaderEl.classList.add('hidden');
    preloaderEl.classList.remove('visible');
  });
```

```css
#preloader {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: visible;
      background: #fbfbfb url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/3.7.0/processing.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
    
.visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="preloader" class="visible"></div>
<p>EXAMPLE</p>
```

Вариант 2015 года (**Устарел. Так делать не нужно!**):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
    }, 2000);

  });
});
```

```css
#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #333 url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/file-uploader/3.7.0/processing.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="preloader"></div>
<p>EXEMPLE</p>
```

[Пример на JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/593Lqqnm/25/)

Comment: что-то обновленный пример хуже "устаревшего" :) setTimeout не дает гарантию, что все загрузилось, а большое число может только ухудшить поведение, так как пользователь будет думать, что слишком долго загружается

Comment: Обновленный вариант (2019): он подходит, если мне нужно чтобы прелоадер исчезал только после полной загрузки страницы (скрипты, стили, картинки)?

Comment: @Grundy это всего лишь пример, который демонстрирует логику отображения и скрытия лоадера. setTimeout конечно же должен быть заменен на код, который удовлетворяет именно вашим нуждам (например, на загрузку данных с помощью fetch)

Comment: @Sergey код нуждается в доработке под конкретную задачу. Если просто скопировать его как есть, поведение будет, скорее всего, не таким, как вам необходимо

Comment: а какие задачи могут быть? обычная задача: цель - прелоадер исчезает после полной прогрузки css, js и исходного кода страницы.

Comment: @Sergey для этой задачи логику скрытия лоадера нужно просто разместить самым последним тегом script

Comment: тоесть вариант 2015 года мне идеально подходит? иногда пробивает при первом посещении сайта, и на долю секунды успевает показать внешний вид сайта.

Comment: @ФоминаЕкатерина, из примера это тяжело понять, timeout кажется частью решения

Comment: @Grundy Предлагаю вам оформить ниже еще один ответ, из которого сразу будет понятно как и что надо делать

Comment: @ФоминаЕкатерина, зачем, если можно улучшить твой?

Comment: @Grundy Я не против, улучшай мой. Предлагаю оформить пример на JSFiddle, а затем я внесу его как один из вариантов реализации решения данной проблемы

Comment: вариант 2015 года работает нормально.. но есть нюансы. почему то, пробивает и показывает часть стиля моего сайта, которым управляет подгрузка стиля внешне <link rel="stylesheet".

Comment: @ФоминаЕкатерина, почему для моей задачи вы написали что логику скрытия лоадера нужно просто разместить самым последним тегом script? Разве не в самом начале кода нужно разместить эти функции?

Comment: @Sergey в рамках комментариев этот вопрос не решить. Создайте вопрос, опишите там все подробности и будет хорошо, если будет приложен пример демонстрирующий проблему. Пока я не понимаю что у вас там загружается и каким боразом

Comment: @ФоминаЕкатерина, так вы написали для этой задачи логику скрытия лоадера нужно просто разместить самым последним тегом script. Мой вопрос почему именно самым последним?

Comment: @Sergey
1. Для какой "для этой задачи"? Еще раз повторяю: для того, чтобы получить помочь по конкретному вопросу, рекомендуется оформлять это как отдельный вопрос. 
2. У выполнения js скриптов есть определенный порядок: от самого первого тега, до последнего скрипты выполняются по-порядку, если нет асинхронных обращений к серверу. То есть, чтобы скрыть лоадер именно после того как все css, js будут загружены, нужно разместить логику скрытия лоадера просто ниже всех остальных скриптов.

Comment: @Sergey Добавлю. Именно в примере 2015 года порядок скриптов может быть какой угодно, потому что за статусом загрузки страницы следит jquery