# Как сделать прелоадер, который исчезает только после полной загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript

Как сделать прелоадер для сайта который будет исчезать только после полной загрузки страницы (скрипты, стили, картинки)? Нужно чтобы страница отображалась посетителю в полностью загруженном виде.

Comment: нужно убирать прелоадер тогда, когда страница полностью загрузится

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: что именно? убрать прелоадер? Нужно просто присвоить или убрать класс у элемента в нужный  момент

Comment: Как сделать прелоадер, который исчезает только после полной загрузки страницы?

Comment: Так об этом же в первом комментарии есть. Плюс, чем не устраивают решения из вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427668/186999 ?

Comment: Опять же разные варианты могут быть от того, что за страница, кто как и когда что в ней загружает.

Comment: Обновленный вариант (2019): он подходит, если мне нужно чтобы прелоадер исчезал только после полной загрузки страницы (скрипты, стили, картинки)?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110157/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergey).